# need help in fixing sql connection error C#.net sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting an error while retrieving connections strings from app.config file using vs2010 C#.net/sql server. My codes are below can some one pls help me in this.Can someone pls help me to fix this issue. I am working in client server env accessing DB from server.

```
private void btnSendEmailtoDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionStrings= GetDatabaseConnection().ToString();
        //if (GetDatabaseConnection() != null)
        //{
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                InsertEmailData(connectionStrings, dr["Subject"].ToString(), dr["Content-Description"].ToString(), dr["From"].ToString(), dr["To"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateSent"].ToString()), loginTextBox.Text);

            }
        //}
    }

private string GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["emailDownloadsManagement"].ConnectionString;
        return connectionString;
    }

private void InsertEmailData(string connectionString, string emailSubject, string emailBodyDescription, string emailsFrom, string emailsTo, DateTime emailsDate, string emailsUser)
{
    // define INSERT query with parameters
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblEmailDownload (emailMessageSubject, emailMessageBodyDescription, emailFrom, emailTo, emailDate, emailUser) " +
                       "VALUES (@emailMessageSubject, @emailMessageBodyDescription, @emailFrom, @emailTo, @emailDate, @emailUser) ";

        // create connection and command
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            // define parameters and their values
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailMessageSubject", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = emailSubject;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailMessageBodyDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5000).Value = emailBodyDescription;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = emailsFrom;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailTo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = emailsTo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailsDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = emailsDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = emailsUser;

            // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
            //if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            //{
            //    cmd.Connection.Close();
            //}
            cn.Open();  // the error is here saying ServerVersion   'cn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    string {System.InvalidOperationException} and saying connection is closed
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

my app.config file details are below looks like everything is correct but there is an error

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="emailDownloadsManagement" connectionString="Data Source = SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=administrator;Password=password;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and here is the more detailed error description.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

one more thing found can some one pls correct
Hi All, while debugging found this format of connection string which looks not fine fine because of \ can someone pls help me to correct "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\administrator;Password=password"  is this userid with \ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...  and i have tried changing from windows authentication to sql authentication but error is same and exists now also. pls help...

Comment: please specify the details of the error: "there is an error". What error message is it throwing to you?

Comment: Is this error occuring when running after deployment? In other words does it work fine from Visual Studio?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe- the detailed error is-  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: @Raghu - during development when debugging the code to insert values in DB

Comment: Hi All, I have searched a lot for answers related to this error but none of them are working for me in any case   - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: pls help i am getting mad by this error.... pls

Comment: I see you have Integrated Secutiry on, but yhat you're using Integrated Security as well? "User Id=administrator;Password=password;Integrated Security=True". How will you be connecting to your db, via Windows user(s) or Db-user(s)?

Comment: I am using vs2010 c#.net/sql server 2008 R2 for windows appln.

Comment: i am using windows authentication for connecting sql server and even i have tried removing Integrated Security from config file bu that didn't helped

Comment: Use http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ to check the format of your connection string is correct.

Comment: try removing user id & password already. If you're using integrated security (windows user) then you don't need those. Keep "integrated security=true". Also check with SQL Server Management Studio whether, with the user you're running Visual Studio, you can connect to the database & server. If not, it's to do with permissions, or, that your SQL Server doesn't accept logins from win-users (integrated security).. Have you set up the SQL server yourself?

Comment: Hi Daniel, i have checked and format is according to that. pls let me know if you found any mismatch and i have tried with many other possible scenarios

Comment: hi yves , i have tried removinguserid & pwd but didn't work and same error msg is ServerVersion = 'cn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Well, as others have said, using Integrated Security and also supplying a user name and password makes *no sense*. You should update your question to include the connection strings you have tried (first checking that they are valid).

Comment: @YvesSchelpe i have tried accessing remotely to that server with same credentail using RDC and i am able to access that db so that permission is there i think to access it

Comment: Hi All, while debugging found this format of connection string which looks not fine fine because of \\ can someone pls help me to correct "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\\administrator;Password=password"  is this userid with \\ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...  and i have tried changing from windows authentication to sql authentication but error is same and exists now also. pls help...

Comment: can anyone pls help on this and let me know if there is anything doing wrong in this code part...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates it cannot connect to the database server using the connection string you have provided.  Since you are using integrated security it will try and connect as the user that is set under the iis app pool, you cannot provide a windows username and password in the connection string. If you don't use integrated authentication then you can supply a username and password but this needs to be a SQL server user not a windows user.

Comment: hi ben, as you said i tried this way don't use integrated authentication then you can supply a username and password but didn't work  and also tried removing usrname & pwd added integrated security=true but that also not worked any thoughts on this

Comment: When you removed integrated authentication did you supply the username and password of a SQL server user? If so can you connect to the database as that user in SQL management studio?

Comment: yes i supplied username and password but didn't work and with same username and password  but i am able to login thru SSMS and explored the db objects

Comment: Hi All, while debugging found this format of connection string which looks not fine fine because of \\ can someone pls help me to correct "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\\administrator;Password=password"  is this userid with \\ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...  and i have tried changing from windows authentication to sql authentication but error is same and exists now also. pls help...

Comment: I am confused. abcxyz\\administrator is not a valid SQL server username so that is never going to work, but neither would any other valid but incorrect username.  Can you set up a valid SQL server user, connect with that user and password using SQL management studio, once sucessfull, try using that in the connection string. If that still doesn't work then we can look into other posible connection issues, but if with a username that can't possibly be correct then obviously it will never work.

Answer (score 0):

first u check u r able to login to database from current loginid and password. and check the database name.

and after that check in webconfig for connectionstring(correct name).

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["emailDownloadsManagement"].ConnectionString.ToString()

and after that try your above code.

Comment: hi udham   thanks for your response   and yes i am able to login and explore the db objects using that loginid & pwd.                   , while debugging found this format of connection string which looks not fine fine because of \\ can someone pls help me to correct "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\\administrator;Password=password"  is this userid with \\ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...  and i have tried changing from windows authentication to sql authentication but error is same and exists now also. pls help...

Comment: use sql authentication and add below code in web config and inside connection string <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Database=databasename;Server=servername;User Id=userid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: hi udham i have followed the same though didn't work do u think double salsh\\ gets concatenated in front of userid is the causing one to this error. but i don't think so.  "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\\administrator;Password=password" is this userid with \\ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to insert the exact same amount of parameter values into your table......... @emailMessageID could be the culprit as the insert statement does not look right. Also try putting your whole insert statement on one line without the '+' join.  Connection looks ok but I can't really say without being at your end.

hope this helps

Christian

Comment: Not sure how this helps. The question indicates they can't access the server.

Comment: i tried removing + but ended up with same error which is A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: you still have too many parameters for the insert statement - @emailMessageID

Comment: hi thanks for pointing that but i have removed it though didn't work and still got the same error which i have got earlier and that's opening connection issue... pls help to fix this

Comment: Hi All, while debugging found this format of connection string which looks not fine fine because of \\ can someone pls help me to correct "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=emails;User Id=abcxyz\\administrator;Password=password"  is this userid with \\ is causing not to open connection. Pls help...  and i have tried changing from windows authentication to sql authentication but error is same and exists now also. pls help...